# Open an editor in debug in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: debugging, editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I'm developing an Eclipse application that allows to develop PDE modules. Note that this application has an own workspace.
I have the following question for you:
Is possible to open a GraphicalEditor in debug mode, using all plugins projects that are in the application workspace?

If yes, how can i do it?

thanks in advance
Mirko

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an instance of Eclipse debug the same instance...

But you can run a new instance of Eclipse with you extra plug-ins and debug that. Simply, select the plug-ins in question, right-click, "Debug As..." -> "Eclipse Application". You can adjust the used plug-ins and/or features later for a faster start-up...